# Writing "interactive timely" text on an html page using JS script

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a Javascript that will be automatically writing "timely" text on an html page. As an example I want it to write "Hello world" but one letter at a time every one second.

If you are aware of any example of such code that I can take a look at, I will be really pleased.

Thank you.

Comment: Commonly referred to as a [typewriter effect](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+typewriter) - Google is your friend, please feel free to lean on it in times of need.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var index = 0;
var hello = "hello world";
function write()
{
    document.write(hello.substr(index,1));
    index++;
    if(index >= hello.length)
    {
        clearInterval(i);
    }
}
setInterval(write, 1000);
```